# How to start method when a value of a global variable changes?

Tags: ios, xcode, methods

Sorry for not having any code in my question!
I want to implement a program where i want to start gyroscope updates when the accelerometer x axis reading exceeds a certain threshold value. When gyroscope is activated i need to stop accelerometer updates as well. The way , i planed is to take accelerometer data to a global variable and then compare it with the an if condition. if it satisfies the condition i need to send the signal to start gyro update and stop accel update?

I can implement code about accel and gyro updates but the problem is i have no idea how to start gyro data n stop accel data when the value of global variable exceeds the threshold value? Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

you can use getter and setter to change variable. in setter you can check any condition you want. then you just can, for example, post notification about reaching needed threshold.

```
- (void) setNeededValue:(valueType)newValue;
{
    neededValue = newValue;

    if( neededValue > threshold )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: someConstStringAsNotificationName object: self];
    }
}
```

to receive notification use this code in any class you want to receive it by calling

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationHandler) name:someConstStringAsNotificationName object:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable guidance! If possible can you show me the logic with a piece of code! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me, you just need to try it out.  Pseudo:

```
if ( globalVariable > thresholdValue ) {
    stopAccelData();
    startGyroData();
}
```

Comment: Smart Pseudo code bro! :) But i want to control accel updates and gyro updates using two different methods rather than using one! :)

Comment: You could also take the approach of using something like a mutex.  That way, only one process could be running at a time, and also notify other processes when it has completed.

Comment: Can u suggest me any references? :)